# Contar total e repassar valor para parágrafo em javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma tabela de livros e preciso

1. Contar a quantidade de livros lidos
2. Encontrar um parágrafo com a classe "**total**" e depois
3. Escrever o valor total encontrado dentro dessa classe.

Eu consegui fazer fazer isso usando o console.log, ou seja, o total de "li" é 3, mas eu não sei como inserir esse valor total, no caso 3, dentro do parágrafo

. Como fazer isso?

```
  <div class="listadelivros">
  <ul>
    <li>
    Livro 1
    </li>
     <li>
    Livro 2
    </li>
     <li>
    Livro 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p class="total"></p>
```

```js
let contarLivros = document.querySelectorAll(".listadelivros ul li");
console.log(contarLivros.length);
```

```html
  <div class="listadelivros">
  

  <ul>
    <li>
    Livro 1
    </li>
     <li>
    Livro 2
    </li>
     <li>
    Livro 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p class="total"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para inserir um valor dentro de uma tag, você pode usar o `innerText`. Basta selecionar o parágrafo e passar a informação dessa maneira:

```
let contarLivros = document.querySelectorAll(".listadelivros ul li");
console.log(contarLivros.length);

const p = document.querySelector("p.total");
p.innerText = contarLivros.length;
```

o `console.log()` geralmente é utilizado para fins de debug. Caso queira debugar, ele será necessário neste trecho, caso não seja necessário basta remover a linha.